# aws cloudfront does not replicate s3 bucket static website correctly after 48 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I hosted a static website on aws s3 and added cloudfront to route 53 linking it to the domain name.
I noticed that an html change I implemented/uploaded on the s3 bucket code more than 48 hours ago is not shown on cloudfront yet (whereas the s3 endpoint obviously has shown it correctly since the change).
Strangely enough, other html changes I just implemented/uploaded on s3 30 minutes ago are already correctly shown via cloudfront.
Shouldn't cloudfront refresh itself every 24 hours to cache origin content?
Just for reference the code snippet I am talking about is related to a menu navigation bar, to transform the menu in a drop-down-list once the display is restricted.

```html
  <div class="mainmenu-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Is there anything I can do to have cloudfront replicate exactly the s3 content? So far I just waited for 24 hours, just wanted to avoid incurring the cache refreshing additional charges but now it scares me that more than 48 hours have gone by with no result.
Thank you, wish you a good day,

Answer (score 1):

General strategies for updating CloudFront (CF) distro are listed in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/UpdatingExistingObjects.html). If these basic strategies are not working, as seems to be the case for you, you can force CF to [Invalidate Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html).

However, please note that:

> The first **1,000 invalidation** paths that you submit per month are **free**; you pay for each invalidation path over 1,000 in a month.

Comment: I have just invalidated the index as per your suggestion. The cloudfront console shows a successful completion of the invalidation (30 minutes ago). Unfortunately I see no change. I ask myself how is it possible that the s3 endopoint has been showing the website correctly in the last 48+ hours and cloudfront doesn't do it. What else could be the problem? thank you

Comment: @MicheleGiglioni Maybe your browser caches the website?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. I tried on both firefox and safari eliminating the cache on both. Maybe I will wait one more day or two and if it doesn't update i will create a new cloudfront distribution and attach it to the domain

Comment: Its strange the CF would not delete it. Maybe this one file is fetched from somewhere else then CF. Difficult to speculate at this stage.

Comment: it's not one file. It's a piece of code in each one of the html pages (total number is 16). Basically it allows, when the display window is restricted (like on a smartphone) to click on a drop-down-list to see each tab of the menu. As mentioned it has been working perfectly on all 16 html pages on the s3 endpoint for the last 48+ hours. Appreciate your help anyway pal!

Comment: @MicheleGiglioni Sadly don't have more ideas. Sorry.